# I wonder if Wordpress uses any type of configurational inheritance from main site to the nested site

Tags: php, wordpress

With Wordpress I had only some experience in setting up different sort of plugins, never dealt with how it's done on system and engineering level. Now I'm going to move my site from host to another host and need some advise over the following thing:

with my existing hosting I host 2 web sites: root one (andrtsa.com) and one I created later (oksana.photography) that I noticed is shown with its own content under [public_html]. I do not need old root site, it's outdated, I only want to migrate new one in subfolder. I wonder If I can just take (copy) whatever I have in root folder of my site (folders like [public_ftp], [perl5], [.cpanel] etc), and I'm removing everything from public_html except [oksana.photography] folder which whole content I copy to its parent [public_html] folder like on the picture:

[image]

I wonder if nothing. My only concern is that Wordpress (php) might use some form of folder to subfolder inheritance, like if I remove something important that is in public_html and missing in [oksana.photography] configuration file or something I could be in trouble, not sure though if anything like this is used in Wordpress. Please advise

Comment: Unless you have done some manual changes to the WP files, it simply looks like you have two separate WP applications. Then you should be able to move one and not the other. Just test it by taking the site you want and try to get it running by itself locally?

Comment: I'll test it, thanks. Just before testing I wanted to make sure it's feasible coz manual migration is more time consuming comparing to one provided by some WP plugins, but those plugins won't separate first site from second, so I'll try manually migrate everything.

Comment: Are both sites using the same database and tables?

Comment: not sure. How can I check that? I personally did not implement anything to use dbs, but plugins I installed on both sites could do.